# how do i make create html in the right place using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-modal

I was trying to create HTML elements using javascript,
i managed to create them but they appear in the wrong place.
im also using bootstrap.

the problem im stuck at the moment right now is how do i create html elements on specific places in my page.

in this case, under my modal-body div-> container fluid div -> new row div

```js
let a = 1;

//function to create text area and date picker with unique id
function create() {

  let input = document.createElement("input");
  input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
  input.setAttribute('class', 'form-control');
  input.setAttribute("id", "txt" + a);

  let pickdate = document.createElement("input");
  pickdate.setAttribute('type', 'date');
  pickdate.setAttribute("id", "pickdate" + a);

  document.body.appendChild(pickdate);
  document.body.appendChild(input);

  a++;
}
```

```css
.col-md-11 {
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: right;
  border: 2px solid white;
}

.col-md-2 {
  background-color: lightblue;
  text-align: right;
  border: 2px solid white;
}

.col-md-8 {
  background-color: pink;
}

.col-md-4 {
  background-color: orange;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid white;
}

.col-md-1 {
  background-color: violet;
  align: left;
}

.col-md-5 {
  background-color: grey;
  align: left;
}

.col-md-3 {
  background-color: yellow;
  align: left;
}

.col-md-10 {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<body>

  <div class="container mt-5">

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-2">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Add New Record</button>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-8">

        <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text">

      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1">
        <select name="sort" id="sort">
          <option value="" disabled selected>choose</option>
          <option>Date Filed</option>
          <option>Name</option>
          <option>Purpose</option>
          <option>Status</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row mt-3">
      <div class="col-md-10">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat, iusto?</div>

      <div id="actions" class="col-md-2">
        <button id="editbtn" class="btn btn-success">Edit</button>
        <button id="delbtn" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="delwarning()">Delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Modal start-->
  <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">

    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">


      <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Add new Record</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-1"><label for="name">Name:</label></div>
              <div class="col-md-11"><input class="form-control input-lg" type="text"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-1"><label for="name">Purpose:</label></div>
              <div class="col-md-11"><input class="form-control input-lg" type="text"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-1"><label for="name">Date:</label></div>
              <div class="col-md-3"><input class="form-control input-lg" type="date"></div>
              <div class="col-md-2"><label for="name">Destination/s:</label></div>
              <div class="col-md-5"><input class="form-control input-lg" type="text"></div>
              <div class="col-md-1"><button id="addmore" class="btn btn-success" onclick="create()">more</button></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: What does "wrong place" mean, please be specific

Comment: Replace `document.body` with whatever "the right place" is

Comment: `document.querySelector('.modal-body')` instead of `document.body`.

Comment: @Paulie_D oops my bad. i'll edit the question.  i want them to appear inside my
modal-body, container-fluid, new row div

Comment: Where ist the element that runs `create()`?

Comment: According to your included CSS you are using Bootstrap 5. According to your HTML you are using Boostrap 4. According to your quesion you don't mention it. Which one is it? Very low quality question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are appending elements to the body, instead get the modal node and append to it like below.

```
function create() {

  let input = document.createElement("input");
  input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
  input.setAttribute('class', 'form-control');
  input.setAttribute("id", "txt" + a);

  let pickdate = document.createElement("input");
  pickdate.setAttribute('type', 'date');
  pickdate.setAttribute("id", "pickdate" + a);

  document.querySelector('.modal-body').appendChild(pickdate);
  document.querySelector('.modal-body').appendChild(input);

  a++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your create function, create a new `div.row` first. Append the elements to that, and finally append the row to the modal.

```js
let a = 1;

//function to create text area and date picker with unique id
function create() {
  let row = document.createElement('div');
  row.className = 'row';
  let input = document.createElement("input");
  input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
  input.setAttribute('class', 'form-control');
  input.setAttribute("id", "txt" + a);

  let pickdate = document.createElement("input");
  pickdate.setAttribute('type', 'date');
  pickdate.setAttribute("id", "pickdate" + a);

  row.append(pickdate, input);
  document.querySelector('.modal-body .container-fluid').appendChild(row);

  a++;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">


<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#myModal" onclick="create()">Add New Record</button>

<!-- Modal start-->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-bs-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Add new Record</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1"><label for="name">Name:</label></div>
            <div class="col-md-11"><input class="form-control input-lg" type="text"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1"><label for="name">Purpose:</label></div>
            <div class="col-md-11"><input class="form-control input-lg" type="text"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1"><label for="name">Date:</label></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"><input class="form-control input-lg" type="date"></div>
            <div class="col-md-2"><label for="name">Destination/s:</label></div>
            <div class="col-md-5"><input class="form-control input-lg" type="text"></div>
            <div class="col-md-1"><button id="addmore" class="btn btn-success" onclick="create()">more</button></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```